# Report Expressions - Cognos Report Expressions translated into SSRS 2012 Report Expressions

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to SSRS 2012. I have found many answers throughout my learning on this forum which is why I decided to join and hopefully I will be able to help others out as well in their learning. I have one question though that I can't seem to find an answer to.

We're currently using Cognos Reporting for our reports but are switching to Microsoft Reporting Services 2012 (SSRS). The Report Expressions in Cognos are not the same as in Microsoft Reporting Services so it is causing a problem for me. This results in new learning opportunities too, of course.

This query is from Cognos:

```
if([query1].[fw.ShipQty] > 0) then [query1].[fw2_cost]/[Query1].[fw2_ShipQty].
```

I am not sure how I would write it out. I understand that I may be writing it out the wrong way but below is how I wrote it into Microsoft Reporting Services Expression Builder:

```
=IIF(Fields!fw1_ShipQty.value > 0, Fields!fw1_cost.Value / Fields!fw1_ShipQty)
```

If anyone would be able to help me out, that would be the best. If you also have comments on my post, don't hesitate to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your trying to avoid a divide by zero error.  ( I sound just like Microsoft Clippy there ).

Your problem is that the IIF function always evaluates all clauses passed regardless of which portion (the true value or the false value) is returned.

In short, you'll still get the divide by zero error on the clause even though you're testing for zero first.  You'll have to re-think how you are testing for divide by zero errors.

The following is good [advice provided on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cb0d016b-83be-4720-8ffc-c4af48f4a5a0/ssrs-iif-syntax?forum=sqlreportingservices):

With SSRS use a pattern like this to avoid division by zero:

```
=iif(B=0, 0, A / iif(B=0, 1, B))
```

Comment: RThomas, thank you very much for your input. It was exactly what I was looking for! I also learned how IIF "works". Thanks again!